# Spring: UnsatisfiedDependencyException even though qualifier property matches

Tags: spring

**Summary:** I am working with some sample Spring code (from javabrains.io).  Basically this code illustrates the use of the `@Qualifier` annotation in the Java file.  One of the bean elements (in `spring.xml`) has a qualifier that matches the value of the `@Qualifier` annotation but even then `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` is thrown.

---

**Details:** The `Circle` class has a method which accepts a `Point` object and which has the following annotations:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("circleRelated")
```

In `spring.xml` we have three Point beans: `pointA`, `pointB` and `pointC`.  `pointA` has the property attribute set to `circleRelated`.  One would expect that since this bean meets the qualifier criterion (i.e. value = "circleRelated"), at initialization time autowiring should complete without any hitch. However, `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` is thrown.  The source code follows:

---

**Point.java**

```
package org.koushik.javabrains;

public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**Circle.java**

```
package org.koushik.javabrains;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Circle {
    private Point center;

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("circleRelated")
    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }


    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing Circle");
        System.out.println("Circle: Center point is: " + center.getX() + ", " + center.getY());
    }

}
```

**DrawingApp.java**

```
package org.koushik.javabrains;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        Circle circle = (Circle) context.getBean("circle");
        circle.draw();
    }
}
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <bean id="pointA" class="org.koushik.javabrains.Point">
        <qualifier value="circleRelated"/>
        <property name="x" value ="0"/>
        <property name="y" value ="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointB" class="org.koushik.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value ="-20"/>
        <property name="y" value ="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointC" class="org.koushik.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value ="20"/>
        <property name="y" value ="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="circle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.Circle">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

`<context:annotation-config/>`

tag in your spring.xml

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html)

> Use of these annotations also requires that certain BeanPostProcessors
>   be registered within the Spring container. As always, these can be
>   registered as individual bean definitions, but they can also be
>   implicitly registered by including the following tag in an XML-based
>   Spring configuration (notice the inclusion of the 'context'
>   namespace):

On a side note , any specific reason you are using xml based configuration ? Though spring supports xml configurations , it is long since people have moved to Annotations based configuration.I recommend that it is worth exploring annotations based route.